# Netbook not working properly

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, cpu, netbook

I am having a netbook of dell inspiron mini with specifications-

- Operating System: Windows 7 Starter 32-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1
  System Model: Inspiron 1018
- Processor: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455   @ 1.66GHz (2 CPUs), ~1.7GHz
           Memory: 2048MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 2038MB RAM
        Page File: 1921MB used, 2153MB available
      Windows Dir: C:\Windows
  DirectX Version: DirectX 11
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found

Now the problem is that my netbook was working fine until i opened it after 3-4 days. My PC became very slow and if i wanted to open a folder or a file it didn't open and if i restarted or tried to shutdown the pc it didn't gave any response .
**I TRIED**

1. Running a Full and Smart scan in avast and a bitdefender quickscan;result was nothing.
   2.Tried to Boost my PC by clean master,ccleaner.
   3.Ran scan of malwarebytes-antimalware; result was nothing.

Comment: try system restore to earlier working date, it could be something you installed or an update that did not work out.

Comment: You are telling me to google it but be logical my chrome and windows explorer are not opening they open only once in a hundred so how can i?

Comment: Can anyone tell me the exact problem that my netbook has?

Comment: Hey nosboy listen i did that nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a program like IO Bit Uninstaller or Revo - google them - to go through a listing of your installed programs and remove anything that you installed recently other than a **single** antivirus client. This includes removing the PC Boosters and things of that nature (keep ccleaner and run it and it's registry component at the very end of this whole thing). Allow it to perform a powerful scan and delete remnants also.

2) Use the above program to also delete nearly all of the things dell pre-installed. You should be able to recognize these as various games, "update utilities", eco tools, power managers and more. Keep anything that says "hotkey" or sounds like it operates those special function buttons all over your keyboard. Nearly all of them will be labeled from the same set of developers.

3) Use a tool like autoruns (google it) to reduce **logon, explorer, scheduled tasks, and services** items that don't seem relevant. Just uncheck the boxes, you can't go too wrong as long as you don't venture outside those categories.

4) Understand that you have an Intel Atom processor and this computer will never be very fast. Consider upgrading your HDD to an SSD to nearly double the "responsiveness" of it, however.